# EF return columns data as list or array

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two tables, which have following foreign key

Poll(CreatedBy) --> CreateBy(ID)

[image]

On performing join, I am getting data as following:

[image]

I want to write an query using EF (if possible) to return result as:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "users": [
        {
            "email": "abc.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "users": [
        {
            "email": "xyz.test"
        },
        {
            "email": "tet.com"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the two classes?

Comment: You didn't post any c# classes, EF queries or entities, or your JSON serialization code. You started from a cup of flour and asked how to make carrot cake. The text you posted is a JSON string generated from C# classes, it has nothing to do with EF. The database diagram you posted shows just tables, not EF entities, their relations or the DbContext's configuration. EF is an ORM, not a model of the database or a connection. *The ORM* will generate all appropriate JOINs based on the relations between entities

Comment: For example assuming the DbContext is configured correctly, you wouldn't need any joins. A simple `context.Polls.Select(poll=>new {Id=poll.PollId,Users=poll.CreatedBy.Select(u=>u.EmailAddress)})` is probably enough to get the data. The creators should be available as a property on `Poll`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the class structure like below:

```
public class Poll
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CreateBy> CreateBy { get; set; }
}

public class CreateBy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Poll")]
    public int PollId { get; set; }
}
```

Data source:

[image]

[image]

Linq query:

```
var result = (from p in _context.Poll.ToList()
                join c in _context.CreateBy on p.ID equals c.PollId
                group p by p.ID into g
                select new
                {
                    id = g.Key,
                    users = g.Select(x => x.CreateBy.Where(z => z.PollId == g.Key).Select(y => new { email = y.EmailAddress })).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: EF doesn't need explicit joins, it generates them from the relations between entities. Loading every poll in memory before filtering is a *very* bad idea too